# Best way to swap first 4 chars with last 4 chars of string?

Tags: string, bash, swap

What's the way to swap first 4 chars with last 4 chars of string?

e.g. I have the string 20140613, I'd like to convert that to 06132014.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ f=20140613
$ g=${f#????}${f%????}
$ echo $g
06132014
```

For dealing with longer strings something like the following is needed. (With inspiration from konsolebox's answer.)

```
echo ${f:(-4)}${f:4:${#f} - 8}${f:0:4}
```

Comment: I like this one, clean and simple :) So does #???? designate first 4 and %???? designate last 4?

Comment: @etan-reisner: I've voted for your answer because it (1) will run in any POSIX shell, and (2) it relies exclusively on built-ins and will not spawn new processes.

Comment: @user3388884: Yes, it's called "parameter expansion", and here is an authoritative reference for it: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

Comment: @user3388884 The `?` is shell glob for any single character. The `#` and `%` match at the start and end of the variable value as per the link from mkalkov (and the bash man page).

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if input is more than 8 characters like: `f=2014abcd0613`

Comment: @anubhava True, though that's a failing of many of the existing answers and simply a mistake of an overly specific (to the exact question asked) answer.

Comment: +1 for the last echo line, it looks the parenthesis or double-parenthesis are not always necessary though: echo ${f:(-4)}${f:4:(${#f} - 8)}${f:0:4}; echo ${f:0-4}${f:4:${#f} - 8}${f:0:4}

Comment: @lihao Thanks for the prodding about that. When I was first testing it I was getting errors about it but trying it again now it seems to work without those.

Answer (score 3):

Using pure BASH regex:

```
s='20140613'

[[ "$s" =~ ^(.*)([[:digit:]]{4})$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
06132014
```

Comment: +1, but it's sooooo verbose :) I'm not sure why `bash` couldn't have at least picked a shorter name for `BASH_REMATCH`.

Comment: Agreed `BASH_REMATCH` is really silly name.. simple `GROUP` OR `MATCH` would have been enough.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use substring expansion:

```
$ STRING=20140613
$ echo "${STRING:(-4)}${STRING:0:4}"
06132014
```

See [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: Simply: This is THE solution. ;) GREAT!

Answer (score 2):

Using `date` which is optimized for such kind of conversion:

```
$ str="20140613"
$ date +"%m%d%Y" -d "$str"
06132014
```

When you have to convert dates, no need to look so far ;)

Comment: Indeed. For date specific conversions date is quite often the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
STRING="20140613"
STRING=$(echo $STRING | sed 's/\(....\)\(.*\)/\2\1/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 20140613 | sed 's/^\(.\{4\}\)\(.\{4\}\)$/\2\1/g'
06132014
```

Through `perl`,

```
$ echo 20140613 | perl -pe 's/^(.{4})(.{4})$/\2\1/g'
06132014
```

Comment: You could further improve the sed command to `sed -r "s/^(.{4})(.{4})/\2\1/"`.

Answer (score 1):

Or using `awk`:

```
echo 20140613 | awk '{print substr($0,5,7) substr($0,1,4)}'
```

---

Test:

```
~$ echo 20140613 | awk '{print substr($0,5,7) substr($0,1,4)}'
>> 06132014
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Coreutils:

```
input=20140613
output=$(echo $input | fold -w4 | tac | tr -d \\n)
```

If you also need the last line feed, you can replace `tr -d \\n` with `printf %s%s\\n` or just append `&& echo` to the command.

Answer (score 0):

With perl

```
for str in 11112222 1111xxxx2222 111222
do
    echo -n "$str -> "
    echo "$str" | perl -ple 's/^(.{4})(.*)(.{4})$/\3\2\1/'
done
```

produces:

```
11112222 -> 22221111
1111xxxx2222 -> 2222xxxx1111
111222 -> 111222
```

Comment: This kind of task could be done with `sed`. Using a complete technology like perl to make occasional and small things within a shell script is not very pragmatic.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann OMG _WHY_ ? Especially for occasional and small tasks doesn't matter what do you using, important is getting done the task. I'm using `sed` many times, but here was already some `sed` asnwers so added an `perl` one. Strange, in your (nice) answer youre using `date` and not `sed`. :) Maybe you should define what means "small and occassional" and what tasks are "big and common". :) Can you please tell me, why for `small and occasional` tasks is "not pragmatic" to use perl? :)

Comment: @jm666 I prefer to use `date` which is the right shell tool to make date conversions for this particular case. 
But, In general, I think it's not pragmatic to introduce a technology like Perl (or Python, or PHP-cli in the same way) to make little operations like that within a shell script.
In my opinion, it would be better to use `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, bash builtins, other commands like `date` ... within a bash script.

Comment: @IdrissNeumann It is a common misbelief than the `perl` is excellent only for web development and or for some very-hard-to-done-with-other-tools type tasks. This is not true. Perl is _perfectly_ suitable for bash scipts and/or as one-liners. ;) Nevertheless, youre only repeated what you already said, without any explanation - OK - I accepting your point of view. ;)